# ¿Como cargar una font personalizada en Laravel?

Tags: css

Vi muchos ejemplos (la mayoría repetidos), pero no logro cargar la font en mi proyecto laravel.

Tengo mi font en `public/fonts` y en el `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` tengo:

```
// Fonts
@font-face {
    font-family: Metropolis-Bold;
    src: url('/fonts/Metropolis-Bold.tff');
}
```

Pero aun no me carga.

En la consola me sale:

```
app.js:14773 GET http://proyecto.test/fonts/Metropolis-Bold.tff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Entro a esa parte del sitio (`http://proyecto.test/fonts/Metropolis-Bold.tff`) y me sale:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

Uso Laragon, aunque no creo que eso tenga que ver.

Comment: la carga de la fuente la estas haciendo desde un archivo css o desde el archivo html????

Comment: Creo que dejé claro que era en el app.scss donde cargaba la font

Comment: debes agregar el public a tu url pero lo mejor seria cargarlo en el master.blade `<style> @font-face {
    font-family: Metropolis-Bold;
src: url('{{ URL::asset("fonts/Metropolis-Bold.tff") }}';
}</style>`

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí solucionar mi problema (la marcaré como solucionado cuando tenga el privilegio).

1er Fallo:

No me fijé que el archivo era de formato `.otf`, lo tenia `.tff` en el `app.scss`

2do Fallo:

No tenia las fonts donde debían estar. Por ejemplo, mi app.scss es:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Metropolis-Bold;
    src: url('/fonts/Metropolis-Bold.tff');
}
```

Entonces la dirección donde debería guardar los archivos es:

```
(root)/public/fonts
```

Al comienzo lo tenia así, pero en muchos ejemplos colocan `static` cosa que no me fue necesaria

Comment: A los dos días me parece puedes marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Si, aún faltan 20 horas.